# Python websockets command line input

Tags: python, websocket, tornado

I have followed a couple of guides online and am able to get a working websockets app running with tornado. However I want to be able to accept command line input on the tornado server and send this as a message to the connected clients.

The code I use if the same as this

https://github.com/rafaelbrandao/websocket-example-with-tornado/blob/master/server.py

If anyone could advise how to adapt this to accept text from a commandline that would be great

Thanks

James

Answer (score -1):

1. you should have a client program connected with web socket server
2. make the client program able to be used in linux terminal